# angularJS - ng-if and ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to display a field based on the value of a select in my angular app. It should be very simple: when newJob.country === 'Remote' I want my 'city' field to disappear:

HTML:

```
  <body ng-app>
        <div class="form-aside">
          <label>Location</label>
          <select ng-model="newJob.country" class="form-control">
            <option>Remote</option>
            <option>France</option>
            <option>UK</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-aside" ng-if="newJob.country !== 'Remote'">
          <label>City</label>
        </div>
  </body>
```

For some reason it's not working. Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/GcJNePs9zvkejnIATTiw?p=preview

How can i make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `value`for each `<option>` tag.

Then you need to use `ng-show` with `!=` to dynamically display your label or not.

Your plunker should work with this:

```
<body ng-app>
    <div class="form-aside">
      <label>Location</label>
      <select ng-model="newJob.country" class="form-control">
        <option value="remote">Remote</option>
        <option value="france">France</option>
        <option value="uk">UK</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-aside" ng-show="newJob.country != 'remote'">
      <label>City</label>
    </div>
</body>
```

Plunker here : http://plnkr.co/edit/meqpbOVXrH4ANtQlxdoy?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Angular doesn't support `ng-if`.

Try :

```
<div class="form-aside" ng-show="newJob.country != 'Remote'">
```

Or update your version of Angularjs to [1.2.15](http://angularjs.org/), the last stable version.

Comment: Or upgrade angular to at least 1.1.5

Comment: 1.2.15 is better because 1.1.5 is unstable